# display pixel data on serial monitor using ov7670

Tags: arduino-mega

i am trying to get the image data pixel by pixel from ov7670 to serial monitor and to store it into arduino memory which i can access later. i am using arduino mega and the camera is configured to 160x120 resolution. Any suggestions or code from which i can get help from?

Comment: In what way do you want to display "pixel data" on the serial monitor? And what does the serial monitor have to do with storing the data in RAM?

Comment: storing pixel data as a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: And what does that have to do with the serial monitor?

Comment: nothing. i just want to see what and how data is being sent

Comment: You are aware that at 24bpp the image will require about 7x more memory than the Arduino Mega has?  And at 8bpp it will need about 2.5x as much memory as the Mega2560 has? Where were you thinking of storing the image?

Comment: reducing the resolution to 160x120 and using 8bpp will require 19KB which is way less than memory of mega

Comment: No it isn't. The mega has 8kb. Thats much less than 19kb...